# How to build a customised virtual keyboard for any language having its own font

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, virtual-keyboard

I have searched with same title but I did not find the solution which I am actually looking for, That is why I am posting it here. 
I want to build a customised virtual keyboard for some Indian languages which has their own font [not unicode]. Using Php/HTML/Javascript/Jquery. Is there any tools readily available to do this..? 
I found some Virtual keyboards but that were supporting unicode fonts.
Any help/suggestions would be appreciated....

I am using this virtual keyboard in website for search option where people can type the characters of their own language which should match with the font characters stored in the database...

Comment: I don't understand your request..

Comment: Try one of these: [1](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/), [2](http://debugger.ru/demo/projects/virtualkeyboard/), [3](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard), [4](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17128/JavaScript-VirtualKeyboard) or [5](http://project.cahnory.fr/jquery.keyboard/).